# Opening Android Grand Theft Auto 3 saved games with PC version

Tags: android, grand-theft-auto-iii

I was over the moon when GTA3 came out for Android/iOS. However, I'd really like to be able to open my PC-based saved games on my Android version of GTA 3 and vice-versa. Is this possible?

I've already tried copying 2 *.b files from my Android device (Samsung Galaxy SII if that is relevant) and copying them to the GTA3 User Data folder on a PC install, but when I open the game and look at the list of available saved games, the dates are incorrect (year 5142 for instance). I've not yet tried this the other way around.

Comment: I can't see this working to be honest but I wasn't expecting the PC version to even pick up the Android save. Although the year was wrong did the game load? I'm guessing not...?

Comment: No, it crashes when it attempts to load and the game bombs out. On having thought about it a bit more, you are probably right that it won't work - the Android version supports saving the current state of the game (such as player's location, vehicles next to the player etc) as part of the pause/resume functionality, so they have probably had to modify the file format to fit that in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it's **not** possible.

Like you have mentioned in the comments, the way each of the games are saved has changed. Even if the saving system hadn't have changed I am highly confident it wouldn't of been possible since it's *almost* like taking a save file from a PS3 and trying to use it on a PC game. They are two completely different platforms.

Sorry!

Comment: Heh, thanks for clarifying and destroying my dreams :)